# How can I text follow image resize on responsive 2 column layout?

Tags: css, image, text, responsive-design

I have a layout, and it works fine, except for a few minor bumps, and I've spent a whole day working on it, searching google, here, trying other layouts, I even tried Bootstrap, but I got nothing.

The problem is: I'm new to this, and the layout is responsive (I got it from a website, and it's free) and I've found a way to resize the image on w3school.

But the text is just not collaborating. If I fix one thing, I break ten others. 
I cannot make the text stay neatly within the image's proportions. Nor can I set a height so the button below can be at the same baseline as the button inside the div next to it. Anyway, is better if I show you, so here is the fiddler:

https://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyJohnny/y6khb6ez/

And here is the code:

```
<div class="section group"> <!--everythyng's inside this-->

    <div class="col span_1_of_2"> <!--left column-->
        <h1>EXAMPLE_one</h1>

        <img class="imghome" width="300" height="200"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bc/Information_example_page_300px.jpg">
        <!--imgs have w and h set here to work with media query resizing-->

        <p>This is a paragraph. It cannot break mproperply; it must follow proper Syllable Division Rules. As you can see, it will invade the dog's space, as it will not follow image resize.</p>

        <button class="button">button</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col span_1_of_2"> <!--right column-->
         <h1>EXAMPLE_two</h1>

         <img class="imghome" width="300" height="200" src="http://www.starlight-beads.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/8-Tricks-To-Help-You-Take-Care-Of-Your-Pet-300x200.jpg">

         <p>That dog is very hungy. This paragraph, however, should have the same height as the other one.</p>

         <button class="button">button</button>
    </div>

</div>

/*  GRID OF TWO   ============================================================================= */
.span_2_of_2 {
width: 100%;
}

.span_1_of_2 {
width: 49.2%;
text-align:center;
}

.span_1_of_2 p{

width:300px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

 /*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.span_2_of_2 {
width: 100%; 
}
.span_1_of_2 {
    width: 100%; 
}

.span_1_of_2 p{
 max-width: 50%; 
height:auto;
}
}
/*  SECTIONS  
============================================================================= */

.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    }

.section {
    height:300px;
}

 /*  GROUPING  
============================================================================= */


.group:before,
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.group:after {
    clear:both;
}
.group {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

/*  GRID COLUMN SETUP   
==================================================================== */

.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; } /* all browsers except IE6 and lower */

/*  REMOVE MARGINS AS ALL GO FULL WIDTH AT 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col { 
        margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    }
}

 .button {
    margin-top:1em;
}
.imghome {
  max-width:100%;/*  resizes the image */
  height:auto;

}
```

I can't use word-wrap property because I need words to maintain their syntax.

I can't hav

e, for inst

ance, this k

ind of thing.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

jJust use `max-width` instead of `width` on the text

```
.span_1_of_2 p{

    max-width:300px;
}
```

[**See updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/codename0/y6khb6ez/10/)

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to do that, and set a fixed height so that the buttons are always at the same baseline?

Comment: @JohnnyJohnny if you fix the height then you may have a scroll bar because the text may be too long, so you need to consider it :)

Comment: @JohnnyJohnny i edited the code, take a look at this jsfiddle maybe it will help you ...https://jsfiddle.net/kgmcw24j/

Answer (score 1):

check **updated** demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y6khb6ez/16/)

updated CSS:

```
/*  GRID OF TWO   ============================================================================= */

.span_2_of_2 {
  width: 100%;
}

.span_1_of_2 {
  width: 49.2%;
  text-align: center;
}

.span_1_of_2 p {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .span_2_of_2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .span_1_of_2 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .span_1_of_2 p {
    max-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
/*  SECTIONS  ============================================================================= */

.section {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.section {
  /*height:300px;*/
  display: flex;
}

/*  GROUPING  ============================================================================= */

.group:before, .group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

/*  GRID COLUMN SETUP   ==================================================================== */

.col {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.col:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
} /* all browsers except IE6 and lower */

.


/*  REMOVE MARGINS AS ALL GO FULL WIDTH AT 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .col {
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
  }
}

.button {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.imghome {
  max-width: 100%; /*  resizes the image */
  height: auto;
}
```

Try this:

check demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y6khb6ez/11/)

HTML:

```
.span_1_of_2 p {
    max-width:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @JohnnyJohnny answer has been updated with demo. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes, thank, but the button is at the left. I followed what you did first and set the height to 120px. I think it worked. You (both of you) helped me a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JohnnyJohnny check the updated demo my answer button is at center, and I am using the `flex` property which make the solution more scalable than a height solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Media Query. This is a CSS technique to make web responsive.